# Use EF Code First to work against a schema and not a database

Tags: entity-framework

By default I have used to be working with a separate database that EF creates for my Code First Entities and DataContext. At one of the projects I am not allowed to allocate a separate database for the app's sole purpose. But I can create a separate schema in an existing database. Is it possible, and if so, how do I configure EF to work against a separate schema in an existent DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modelBuilder supports that

```
  modelBuilder.entity<yourEntity>.ToTable("NameofTable",schemaToUse);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using code first this should help: http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/